# pass array to scope function from ng-init?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to define a function that can be used to set the default value on a select.  The select is populated correctly, but the value passed into the function is undefined.  How do I accomplish this?

This is my HTML.

```
        <div id="Option" class="form-group" ng-show="Options.length > 0">
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-2" />
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">Options</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" >
                <select name="OptionSelect" id="OptionSelect" class="form-control"
                        ng-model="OptionSelectedId"
                        ng-init="OptionSelectedId = getDefaultOption(Options)" 
                        ng-options="Option.objectKey as Option.label for Option in Options" required >
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the function on the controller scope

```
$scope.getDefaultOption=function(arr){
        return arr=$.grep(arr, function (dropdownObj) {
            return dropdownObj.default === true;
        })[0];  

}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
ng-init="getDefaultOption(Options)"

$scope.getDefaultOption=function(arr){
        arr=$.grep(arr, function (dropdownObj) {
            $scope.OptionSelectedId = dropdownObj.default === true;
        })[0];  

}
```

Comment: just cal function with param in ng-init - your function should set $scope.OptionSelectedId inside js file, not in view like in your example. Hope it helps to solve your problem :)